# invoke setter methods using loop variable and java reflection

Tags: java

i have class called widget..

```
    public class Widget {
          private Long widgetCustomId;
          private String widgetCustomSpace1;
          private String widgetCustomSpace2;
          private String widgetCustomSpace3;
       //.....getter and setter metyhods
 }
```

i want to invoke setter methods using loop variables
my concept is....

```
int max=3;
int min=1;
for(int i=min; i<=max; i++)
{
widget.setwidgetCustomSpace[i]("asaa");
}
```

i know this error.. this done only using reflection.. but i dont know to use reflection.. anyone can plzz help me

Comment: sir,...if  i all setter method add to to list.then how can i invole it by using loop variable

Comment: And if you need more information on how to use reflection, there are lots of tutorials for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In loop follow

`Field field = Widget.class.getClass().getDeclaredField(widgetCustomSpace+i);
field.set(widget, <new-value>);`

Comment: *sonarlint* doesn't like this: `Reflection should not be used to increase accessibility of classes, methods, or fields` (
java:S3011)